# How to lower RAM usage using xarray open_mfdataset and the quantile function

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

I am trying to load multiple years of daily data in nc files (one nc file per year). A single nc file has a dimension of 365 (days) * 720 (lat) * 1440 (lon). All the nc files are in the "data" folder.

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_mfdataset('data/*.nc',
                       chunks={'latitude': 10, 'longitude': 10})

# I need the following line (time: -1) in order to do quantile, or it throws a ValueError:
# ValueError: dimension time on 0th function argument to apply_ufunc with dask='parallelized'
# consists of multiple chunks, but is also a core dimension. To fix, either rechunk into a single
# dask array chunk along this dimension, i.e., ``.chunk(time: -1)``, or pass ``allow_rechunk=True``
# in ``dask_gufunc_kwargs`` but beware that this may significantly increase memory usage.

ds = ds.chunk({'time': -1})

# Perform the quantile "computation" (looks more like a reference to the computation, as it's fast

ds_qt = ds.quantile(0.975, dim="time")

# Verify the shape of the loaded ds
print(ds)

# This shows the expected "concatenation" of the nc files.

# Get a sample for a given location to test the algorithm
print(len(ds.sel(lon = 35.86,lat = 14.375, method='nearest')['variable'].values))
print(ds_qt.sel(lon = 35.86,lat = 14.375, method='nearest')['variable'].values)
```

The result is correct. My issue comes from memory usage. I thought that by doing the open_mfdataset method, which uses Dask under the hood, this would be solved. However, loading "just" 2 years of nc files uses around 8GB of virtual RAM, and using 10 years of data uses my entire virtual RAM (around 32GB).

Am I missing something to be able to take a given percentile value across a dask array (I would need 30 nc files)? I apparently have to apply the chunk({'time': -1}) to the dataset to be able to use the quantile function, is this what makes the RAM savings fail?

Answer (score 0):

This may help somebody in the future, here is the solution I am implementing, even though it is not optimized. I basically break the nc files into slices based on geolocation, and paste it back together to create the output file.

```
ds = xr.open_mfdataset('data/*.nc')

step = 10
min_lat = -90
max_lat = min_lat + step

output_ds = None
while max_lat <= 90:
    cropped_ds = ds.sel(lat=slice(min_lat, max_lat))
    cropped_ds = cropped_ds.chunk({'time': -1})
    cropped_ds_quantile = cropped_ds.quantile(0.975, dim="time")
    if not output_ds:
        output_ds = cropped_ds_quantile
    else:
        output_ds = xr.merge([output_ds, cropped_ds_quantile])
    min_lat += step
    max_lat += step
output_ds.to_netcdf('output.nc')
```

It's not great, but it limits RAM usage to manageable levels. I am still open to a cleaner/faster solution if it exists (likely).